# How to clear out Array before writing new data in for loop in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating a select option for Birthdate which includes Month and Date for testing purposes for now. Everything works fine but the problem is when i select January for instance then it will give days upto 31 but if i 31 remains selected and when i select Febraury it adds previous array with new array i.e. January's 31 days + Febraury 28 days. Please help me how do I clear previous array first then add new one.

Here's The Javascript:

```
    function change(){
    var s1 = document.getElementById('select1');
    var s2 = document.getElementById('select2');
    var i;
    var optionIndex = [];

    if(s1.value === 'January'){
        var i;
        s2.style.display = 'inline-block';
        for(i = 1; i <= 31; i = i + 1){
            optionIndex.push(i);
        }
    }else if(s1.value === 'February'){
         var i;
        s2.style.display = 'inline-block';
        for(i = 1; i <= 28; i = i + 1){
            optionIndex.push(i);
        }
    } 

    var option;
    for(option in optionIndex){ 
        if(optionIndex.hasOwnProperty(option)){
        var pair = optionIndex[option];
        var createOption = document.createElement('option');
        createOption.innerHTML = pair;
        s2.appendChild(createOption);    
        }
    }
}
```

And the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Form Selector</title>
</head>
<body>
    <select id = "select1" name = "select1" onchange="change()">
       <option>Select Year...</option>
        <option>January</option>
        <option>February</option>
        <option>March</option>
        <option>April</option>
        <option>May</option>
        <option>June</option>
        <option>July</option>
        <option>August</option>
        <option>September</option>
        <option>October</option>
        <option>November</option>
        <option>December</option>
    </select>
    <select id = "select2" name = "select2" style = "display:none;">

    </select>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried array.pop(), array.splice() but still doesn't work! Please help me!

Comment: Do you mean clear out the select element's options? If so you have to manipulate that element not your array object. eg `s2.innerHTML = ''`. If not, explain further as `optionIndex` is already set to a new array everytime `change()` is called

Comment: Broken code isn't a good substitute for a properly detailed  explanation of exactly what you expect this code to do

Comment: Something to keep in mind, you should always give values to the options in the mark-up.

Comment: I will keep in mind, Virk! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your issue in not with array - it is good - the problem is that you don't clear s2 when you trigger change. Try

```js
function change(){
            var s1 = document.getElementById('select1');
            var s2 = document.getElementById('select2');
            var i;
            var optionIndex = [];

            if(s1.value === 'January'){
                var i;
                s2.style.display = 'inline-block';
                for(i = 1; i <= 31; i = i + 1){
                    optionIndex.push(i);
                }
            }else if(s1.value === 'February'){
                 var i;
                s2.style.display = 'inline-block';
                for(i = 1; i <= 28; i = i + 1){
                    optionIndex.push(i);
                }
            }
            s2.innerHTML = ""; // You need this

            var option;
            for(option in optionIndex){
                if(optionIndex.hasOwnProperty(option)){
                    var pair = optionIndex[option];
                    var createOption = document.createElement('option');
                    createOption.innerHTML = pair;
                    s2.appendChild(createOption);
                }
            }
        }
```

```html
<select id = "select1" name = "select1" onchange="change()">
       <option>Select Year...</option>
        <option>January</option>
        <option>February</option>
        <option>March</option>
        <option>April</option>
        <option>May</option>
        <option>June</option>
        <option>July</option>
        <option>August</option>
        <option>September</option>
        <option>October</option>
        <option>November</option>
        <option>December</option>
    </select>
    <select id = "select2" name = "select2" style = "display:none;">

    </select>
```

Comment: what about leap year? What about months other than January and February?

Comment: Wooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooohhhhh! Thanks a lot man! Thanks! Thanks! Thanks!

Comment: @charliefl I will manage that! This is just for testing purpose!